# how to inject JS Console in to https page? jsconsole.com

Tags: javascript, remote-debugging, console.log

I have added script tag as follows working on a https website.

```
<script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?xxx-xxxx-x-xx-xxxx"></script>
```

I replaced the http to https still no luck.

```
<script src="https://jsconsole.com/remote.js?xxx-xxxx-x-xx-xxxx"></script>
```

I have downloaded remote.js and added relative path still no luck.

```
<script src="js/remote.js?xxx-xxxx-x-xx-xxxx"></script>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Dear, http://jsconsole.com/ is actually dead, isn't it? What do you want for result? a JSON? a script?

Comment: Well it seems like the website is down at the moment, so that might be the reason why ? Or at least I don't know how we could help you.

Comment: what was the error ?

watch out for 404 errors, if you see these on the chrome developer tools, you'll need to move the files to the correct place

another issue with secured websites is the 'Content-Security-Policy' header, go into chrome dev tools and check if there's a 'Content-Security-Policy' response header, these when set up can block scripts from external domains being executed (which weirdly wouldn't affect relative links...)

Comment: jsconsole.com is still works it has great advantage for ios chrome and other inappbrowsers like facebook itself. However it does not support https